# Internet not working in Ubuntu 16.04.4 VM

Tags: 16.04

I am installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 in Oracle Virtual Box in Windows 10 operating system. I am not able to open any website in Mozilla. How to enable internet ?

Comment: How is the network configured for the guest machine? It should be NAT. If you have an internet connection in your host machine, it will be shared.

Comment: Yes I have NAT in shared settings but not able to connect internet in virtual machine.

Comment: What are "sharing settings"? I mean network settings in VB. You don't need any sharing settings in Windows. That may be the problem.

Comment: I just have checked in the settings of Oracle Virtual box from where I start the Ubuntu. I have selected NAT in that setting but not sure how to check this setting in Ubuntu

Comment: Now restart the VM and all should work if you have a connection on the host.

Comment: No, it does not work.